# Listener in a task works only one time

Tags: c#, winforms, asynchronous, websocket

I have written a complex class called `DonationListener`. This class has a property named `onDonation` that takes a function that will be called when a donation happens. In a simple console program it works fine, but in the more complex WinForms application - not. I am pretty sure that there is no mistake in the class. So I think the problem is in the usage of it. My class works with WebSockets, so I decided to check with the fiddler if the connection lost after the first donation event, and the answer is no, the connection is fine and sending packages that should invoke `onDonation`. Here's the code

```
public string donation_password;
DonationListener dl;

public System.Windows.Forms.PictureBox[,] eliteCards;
public mainForm()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    initializeDonation();
}

public void initializeDonation()
{
    donation_password = db.getPassword();
    dl = new DonationListener(donation_password);
    dl.OnDonation = donation =>
    {
        overlay ol = new overlay();
        string username = donation["username"].ToString();
        User toRide = db.getUserByField(username);
        ol.Show();
        ol.ride(toRide);
    };

    Task t = new Task(() => {
        dl.DoListen();
    });
    t.Start();
}
```

Full class DonationListener(if u need sth from it)

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.WebSockets;
using System.Text;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;

namespace RacheM
{
    public class DonationListener
    {
        private string addUserTemplate = "69:42[\"add-user\",{{\"token\":\"{0}\",\"type\":\"alert_widget\"}}]";


        public Action<JObject> OnDonation = null;
        private readonly string _token;

        public DonationListener(string token)
        {
            _token = token;
        }

        public void DoListen()
        {
            var result =
                DoRequest("GET", "https://socket.donationalerts.ru/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling"); //&t=MYotE0N
            var sid = ExtractToken(result);
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(sid))
            {
                throw new Exception("Failed to get sid");
            }

            var cookie = new Cookie("io", sid, "/", "socket.donationalerts.ru");
            DoRequest(
                "POST",
                $"https://socket.donationalerts.ru/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&sid={sid}",
                string.Format(addUserTemplate, _token),
                cookie
            );

            var waiter = DoWebSocket($"wss://socket.donationalerts.ru/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=websocket&sid={sid}",
                cookie);
            waiter.GetAwaiter().GetResult();
        }


        private static string ExtractToken(string strWidthToken)
        {
            var m = Regex.Match(strWidthToken, "\"sid\":\"(?<token>[^\"]+)\"");
            return m.Groups["token"].Value;
        }

        private static string DoRequest(string method, string url, string data = "", Cookie cookie = null)
        {
            var httpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest) WebRequest.Create(url);

            httpWebRequest.Method = method;
            httpWebRequest.Accept = "*/*";
            httpWebRequest.Headers.Add("Origin", "https://www.donationalerts.com");
            httpWebRequest.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.AcceptEncoding, "gzip, deflate, br");
            httpWebRequest.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.AcceptLanguage, "en-US,en;q=0.9");
            httpWebRequest.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.2; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/68.0.3440.84 Safari/537.36";

            httpWebRequest.Referer = "https://www.donationalerts.com/widget/alerts?group_id=1&token=mcq71m8KVIsojvo5ukFZ";
            if (method == "GET")
            {
                //httpWebRequest.Headers.Remove("Content-Length");
                httpWebRequest.ContentLength = 0;
            }
            else
            {
                httpWebRequest.ContentType = "text/plain;charset=UTF-8";
            }

            if (cookie != null)
            {
                if (httpWebRequest.CookieContainer == null)
                {
                    httpWebRequest.CookieContainer = new CookieContainer();
                }

                httpWebRequest.CookieContainer.Add(cookie);
            }

            if (method == "POST" && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(data))
            {
                using (var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(httpWebRequest.GetRequestStream()))
                {
                    streamWriter.Write(data);
                    streamWriter.Flush();
                    streamWriter.Close();
                }
            }

            var httpResponse = (HttpWebResponse) httpWebRequest.GetResponse();

            var streamReader = new StreamReader(httpResponse.GetResponseStream());

            if(streamReader == null)
            {
                throw new Exception("Connection error");
            }

            using (streamReader)
            {
                return streamReader.ReadToEnd();
            }
        }

        private  async Task DoWebSocket(string url, Cookie cookie)
        {
            using (var ws = new ClientWebSocket())
            {
                var serverUri = new Uri(url);
                ws.Options.Cookies = new CookieContainer();
                ws.Options.Cookies.Add(cookie);
                await ws.ConnectAsync(serverUri, CancellationToken.None);
                var cts = new CancellationTokenSource();

                Task.Factory.StartNew(
                    async () =>
                    {
                        while (true)
                        {
                            try
                            {
                                string srcMessage = string.Empty;
                                ArraySegment<Byte> buffer = new ArraySegment<byte>(new Byte[8192]);

                                using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
                                {
                                    WebSocketReceiveResult result= null;
                                    do
                                    {
                                        result = await ws.ReceiveAsync(buffer, CancellationToken.None);
                                        ms.Write(buffer.Array, buffer.Offset, result.Count);
                                    } while (!result.EndOfMessage);

                                    ms.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
                                    if (result.MessageType == WebSocketMessageType.Text)
                                    {
                                        using (var reader = new StreamReader(ms, Encoding.UTF8))
                                        {
                                            srcMessage = reader.ReadToEnd();
                                        }
                                    }
                                }

                                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(srcMessage)) continue;


                                if (srcMessage.IndexOf("42[\"donation", StringComparison.Ordinal) == 0)
                                {
                                    OnDonation?.Invoke(ParseDonateMessage(srcMessage));
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    Console.WriteLine("no donate msg: " + srcMessage);
                                }
                            }
                            catch (Exception ex)
                            {
                                Console.WriteLine("Error: " + ex.Message);
                            }
                        }
                    }, cts.Token, TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning, TaskScheduler.Default);

                await SendWsMessage(ws, "2probe");
                await SendWsMessage(ws, "5");
                while (ws.State == WebSocketState.Open)
                {
                    await SendWsMessage(ws, "2");
                    Thread.Sleep(25000);
                }
            }
        }

        private static async Task SendWsMessage(WebSocket ws, string message)
        {
            var sendBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(message);
            var cts = new CancellationTokenSource();
            var sendBuffer = new ArraySegment<byte>(sendBytes);
            await
                ws.SendAsync(sendBuffer, WebSocketMessageType.Text, endOfMessage: true,
                    cancellationToken: cts.Token);
        }

        private static JObject ParseDonateMessage(string rcvMsg)
        {
            rcvMsg = rcvMsg.Replace("42[\"donation\",\"", "");
            rcvMsg = rcvMsg.Substring(0, rcvMsg.Length - 2);
            return (JObject)JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Regex.Unescape(rcvMsg));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you show use the code of `DoListen`? Because, why do you think it should 'loop'?

Comment: I've added the full class.

Comment: Tasks aren't threads. There's no need to create a cold task and "start" it with `Task.Start`. They are promises that something will produce a value in the future. Your code starts multiple tasks though without awaiting them, blocks them, starts more tasks inside other tasks.

Comment: The `while (ws.State == WebSocketState.Open)` blocks the current thread. which is probably the gui thread in a winform application.

Comment: The `initializeDonation` method fires off a task just once and never awaits it. This means that anything in that method will be garbage collected when the method ends. This won't work any differently in the console application.

Comment: The thing is - it WORKS one time, the program is working and it's catching the donation, but only one time.

Comment: @J.vanLangen The problem is not in the class, cuz' in the test program (simple console application) it works fine.

Comment: Please provide a [*minimal*, complete example that reproduces the problem](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should try to make this function repeat itself by:

```
bool RunFlag = true // can be set to false somewhere else
public void DoListen()
    {
        while(RunFlag) {
            var result =
                 DoRequest("GET", "https://socket.donationalerts.ru/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling"); //&t=MYotE0N
            var sid = ExtractToken(result);
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(sid))
            {
                throw new Exception("Failed to get sid");
            }

            var cookie = new Cookie("io", sid, "/", "socket.donationalerts.ru");
            DoRequest(
                "POST",
                $"https://socket.donationalerts.ru/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&sid={sid}",
                string.Format(addUserTemplate, _token),
                cookie
                );

                 var waiter = DoWebSocket($"wss://socket.donationalerts.ru/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=websocket&sid={sid}",
            cookie);
            waiter.GetAwaiter().GetResult();
         }
     }
```

Comment: The problem is not in the class. Cuz' in the simple console application it works fine

Comment: At the moment I do not see why  Panagiotis Kanavos should be wrong with his comment.

Comment: Cuz' if what he says is true, than the code will not work. But code is working only one time